# PDF not available in TCM and application is returning content. How to delete non existing content in TCM from Broker DB

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1-hr1, dd4t-java

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1.

The application is returning the content for the items which are not available in CMS.

IN CMS we have different content for the TCM ID mentioned in URL but the application is returning some other content from broker DB. Suggest how to resolve this type of issues.

Comment: Hi Srinivasarao, perhaps you can give an example of the code that is used and results in the PDF(s?) being returned. Is this specific to PDFs, to other binary items or to general content also?

Answer (score 2):

As Velu said, this is most probably an orphan item. It means that it was published with page, but when page was unpublished, it stayed in broker, most probably because references to this binary stayed in broker. So Creating unpublish package for binaries will most probably not work.

For this you need to contact customer support. They will give you queries which you need to execute over database to check which binaries should be deleted. Also you need to make sure that that binary is not referenced any more on content delivery before removing it.

Following images shows where one binary is referenced in Broker database. Please make note that these are just here for you to understand references in broker. **Any tampering over databases without instructions from SDL customer support is UNSUPPORTED.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems to look like your case orphan records in content broker database, or could be a chance those binaries to be used in other pages not sure.

If the item does not exist in the CM, then you cannot send the publish transaction from the CM.

If the binaries are orphaned as in, they were published together with a page, but somehow the page got unpublished, but the binary is still there:  Then it is a data consistency issue, definitely a support case, please raise to SDL support to involve, I would not recommend to do anything by your self to resolve this issue.